# How to calculate hash value of a file in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, hash

I wrote the following program to calculate SHA-256 hash value of a string in Java:

```
public class ToHash {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        byte[] data = "test".getBytes("UTF8");
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] hash = digest.digest(data);
        System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(hash));

    }
}
```

Well, that works fine. In the next step I want to develop it in a way to accept a file and calculate its hash value. My solution is to read whole the file in a string array and the call the `digest()` method on that string array. But there are two problems :

1. I don't have any idea how to read whole the file into an array? Currently I think I must read it line by line and append an array with the new lines!
2. Above methodology  need a lot of memory for big files!

---

This is my current program to read a file:

```
public class ToHash {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\ghasemi\\Desktop\\1.png";
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                byte[] data = sCurrentLine.getBytes("UTF8");
                System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(data));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

It seems that there is no method for `BufferedReader` object to read whole the file with one call.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can read the file and calculate the value of the hash as you go.

```
    byte[] buffer= new byte[8192];
    int count;
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    while ((count = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        digest.update(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    bis.close();

    byte[] hash = digest.digest();
    System.out.println(new BASE64Encoder().encode(hash));
```

This doesn't assume anything about character sets or about the file fitting into memory, and it doesn't ignore line terminators either.

Or you can use a `DigestInputStream.`

Comment: Does the above program work for all big files? (1 GigaByte) for example!

Comment: @Abraham Sure, why not? It only needs 8192 bytes of memory plus whatever the digest uses. You can play with the buffer size but don't make it much smaller.

Comment: I was thought in the `digest.update()` method we append the read data at the end of previous data and so we need a lot of memory(RAM) for big files.

Comment: Excuse me, what is `data` in `count = bis.read(data)` refer to? the same `data` in my program?

Comment: @Abraham No, we recalculate the hash progressively. See the Javadoc. Nothing there about appending data. `data` was a typo.

Comment: Tks. I'm doing this with one hand, other wrist is in plaster.

Comment: Ah! So I wanna thank you again, I hope it get better soon :)

Comment: @HankCa There is no `using` statement in Java.

Comment: My bad; I had been C#'ing when I wrote that.  I meant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016299/does-java-have-a-using-statement#2016311

Comment: This can also be achieved via Guava. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732451/304151